# Async data search filter using react

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select (https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) to search async data.

This is the code:

```
const getOptions = (input) => {
  return fetch(`/users/${input}.json`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    }).then((json) => {
      return { options: json };
    });
}

<Select.Async
  name="form-field-name"
  value="one"
  loadOptions={getOptions}
/>
```

I want to use two select box in a single page. But i'm getting same data in both component since **options** (return { options: json };) is same.

How can I do this?

Thank You

Comment: So you want to have 2 `react-select` from the same "source" from `getOptions` ?

Comment: I need 2 react-select.  Functions can be different or same.

Comment: So what is your problem anyway? There is no problem of using 2 `<Select.Async ... >`.

Comment: The problem is return { options: json }; This options will be same for both <Select.Async ... >

Comment: It is obvious because you are passing the same "source" to `react-select`. `react-select` will take that json `{options: jsonObject}` to render its options list. You have to give it different `options` which fit with your idea/application

Comment: options is default props in react-select.